# Elasticsearch search on forward slash in text field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Elasticsearch mapping:

```
  "description": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "eng_stemmer",
    "fields": {
      "exact": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "exact_lowercase"
      }
    }
  }
```

Analyzers:

```
    "eng_stemmer": {
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "char_filter": [ "html_strip" ],
      "filter": [
        "english_possessive_stemmer",
        "lowercase",
        "english_stemmer"
      ]
    },
    "exact_lowercase": {
      "tokenizer": "keyword",
      "char_filter": [ "html_strip" ],
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ]
    }
```

I am relatively new to Elasticsearch and trying to search on 'C/C' in a text field.
The following query does not seem to work, it returns too many results (it seems to search on 'c c'):

```
{
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "default_field": "description",
     "query": "C\\/C"
   }
 }
}
```

It appears Elasticsearch is removing the forward slash from my search query.
I have also tried using a keyword field but get the following error message (because the field is too long?):

```
Document contains at least one immense term in field=\"description.exact\" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.
```

Any ideas on how I can search on reserved characters inside an analyzed text field?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Standard Tokenizer, the [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) provides grammar based tokenization (based on the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm, as specified in Unicode Standard Annex #29). It will remove all the slashes from your query and during the indexing.

What would be better option for you to use Whitespace tokenizer to solve this problem, for more information check Elasticsearch official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html).